# Changed "partition type" to EFI GPT accidently when default WAS Intel using TESTDISK

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery

So i was trying to recover a failing drive by doing some tests. 
This drive was connected externally.
After some trial and errors - I decided to 'write changes' after going into the EFI GPT category using TestDisk.
I wrote changes, reconnected the drive, now the formally NTFS drive now shows 1234F on bootup.
Instead of detecting the drive as 'Intel' testdisk now detects it as 'EFI GPT partition table type'.
Gparted shows the entire drive as 'unallocated'.
Is there a way I can reverse this?
If not, can I still get the data back by using some recovery tools?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If GParted is showing the disk as unallocated, that suggests that in TestDisk, you opted to "recover" an empty partition set. If this is the case, then your best bet is to go back in with TestDisk (or some similar tool from somebody else) and recover *actual* partitions.

Another possibility is that TestDisk wrote a partition table that GParted doesn't like. (GParted can be quite finicky, and when it sees a partition table it doesn't like, it tends to react as if the disk were unpartitioned.) If this is the case, you may be able to recover your partitions using `gdisk` or some other tool that's not based on libparted. See the [Repairing GPT Disks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) section of the `gdisk` documentation for basic information on GPT recovery operations.